# Printing multiple strings vertically

Tags: python, string

I have a list of string that I would like to print vertically side by side.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

x = ["Please","help","out"]
string = ''

for word in list_of_words:
    string  += word + " "
for x in zip_longest(*string.split(), fillvalue=' '):
    print (' '.join(x))
```

this works but I would like to do this without importing anything.

Input: x = ["Please","help","out"]

Output:

```
    P h o
    l e u 
    e l t
    a p  
    s  
    e
```

Comment: "I would like to do this without importing anything" why? `itertools` is a built-in of python

Comment: Look at the documentation of [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) and you'll see an implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really don't want to use itertools you could do:

```
words = ["Please", "help", "out", "again"]
nwords = len(words)
idx = 0

while idx < max([len(w) for w in words]):
    for i in range(nwords):
        if idx < len(words[i]):
            print(words[i][idx], end=" ")
        else:
            print(" ", end=" ")
    print()
    idx += 1
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [documentation for `itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) it gives you ready solution ("rough equivalent" of library function).

```
def zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=None):
    # zip_longest('ABCD', 'xy', fillvalue='-') --> Ax By C- D-
    iterators = [iter(it) for it in args]
    num_active = len(iterators)
    if not num_active:
        return
    while True:
        values = []
        for i, it in enumerate(iterators):
            try:
                value = next(it)
            except StopIteration:
                num_active -= 1
                if not num_active:
                    return
                iterators[i] = repeat(fillvalue)
                value = fillvalue
            values.append(value)
        yield tuple(values)
```

Simply replace library method with custom one (question is, what's the point though)

Comment: Thank you for the super-fast response!
I am new at this and do not understand at all.

The aim is to make a function that take one argument which should be a list on string, then print them out like I did above.

Sorry if this ins't clear enough. I'm still learning.

Comment: Your initial requirement was not to use library functions. You just put this before the code you posted and replace the call to `zip_longest` from `itertools` with this one. They function pretty much the same and if your original code worked this one will as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple option:

```
words = ["Please", "help", "out"]
maxlen = max(len(w) for w in words)

for i in range(maxlen):
    row = []
    for w in words:
        try:
            row.append(w[i])
        except IndexError:
            row.append(' ')
    print(' '.join(row))
```

Basically, compute the max length of all words. Iterate from 0 to maxlen and try to pick the i-th character from each word. If this fails, use a space instead.